# Getting fbcp to work on a generic ili9341 display

Tags: display, spi, raspberry-pi-desktop

I’m trying to get fbcp to work on my raspberry pi. I’m following the instructions on the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/juj/fbcp-ili9341#building-and-running), however, when I type in make -j it gives an error. I’ll paste the error below

[image]

Comment: You need to raise an issue with the author.

Comment: If you buy items with no data or support don't expect us to help! Did you read the comments by other unsatisfied purchasers.